# Where can I find the Ivory Claw to open a door in Reachwater Rock?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm at Reachwater Rock and I've encountered a series of doors, the first I had to open using the Emerald Claw I found near a body, but now the door's telling me to use an Ivory Claw. **Where can I find it, because I don't have it in my inventory yet.**

[image]

Comment: I just did this, but I have no clue where I found the darn thing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the body of the person you mentioned, there should've been a book that mentioned Folgunthur. That's where you need to go to get the ivory claw: you can find it near Solitude.

> Once inside, you'll find a dead adventurer who has the claw on his person.

Comment: @desaivv, see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38299/what-should-i-do-with-all-these-claws